# run conditional migration sh script via docker compose yml

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, sh

Been googling around for this but I can't get the exact answer.

I am building a mobile app and I want to run additional migration scripts when the environment is "local".

I have a `docker-compose-local.yml` which builds the db

```
  database:
    build:
      context: ./src/Database/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - 1401:1433
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: 'password'
      ENVIRONMENT: 'local'
    networks:
      - my-network
```

and then a Dockerfile with an entrypoint

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entry-point.sh"]`

And then a script that runs migrations.

```
#!/bin/bash

# wait for MSSQL server to start
export STATUS=1
i=0
MIGRATIONS=$(ls migrations/*.sql | sort -V)
SEEDS=$(ls seed/*.sql)

while [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]] && [[ $i -lt 30 ]]; do
    i=$i+1
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -t 1 -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "select 1" >> /dev/null
    STATUS=$?
done

if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then 
    echo "Error: MSSQL SERVER took more than thirty seconds to start up."
    exit 1
fi

echo "======= MSSQL SERVER STARTED ========" | tee -a ./config.log

# Run the setup script to create the DB and the schema in the DB
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i create-database.sql
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i create-database-user.sql

for f in $MIGRATIONS
do
    echo "Processing migration $f"
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i $f
done

# RUN THIS ONLY FOR ENVIRONMENT = local
for s in $SEEDS
do
    echo "Seeding $s"
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i $s
done
```

Currently everything works perfectly fine, except the seeds are added for all environments.

I only want to run the seed scripts if environment = local.
How can this condition be written into this script?

Alternative is there a cleaner way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your goal. Three that come to mind quickly are:

- Insert and check the environment variable in the script (What you are trying to do now)
- Have two versions of the script in the Container and change the entrypoint in the docker-compose file (either with environment variables or by using [multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/))
- Build two different versions of the docker image for local and production environment

With your current setup the first alternative is the easiest:

```bash
# RUN THIS ONLY FOR ENVIRONMENT = local
if [[ "$ENVIRONMENT" == "local" ]]; then
    for s in $SEEDS
    do
        echo "Seeding $s"
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i $s
    done
fi
```